# Identify duplicate - csv dict reader

Tags: python, csv, duplicates

I am iterating over rows of one csv file, I want to skip the row from processing if it is duplicate from any of earlier processed row.

Below is my code:

```
import csv
csv_contents = request.vars['file'].value.decode('utf-8')
file = csv_contents.splitlines()
file_data = [row for row in csv.DictReader(file)]
for data in file_data: 
    #if duplicate, continue. skip the row
```

How to identify if a row is duplicate in a file.

Comment: If you read a csv file with a DictReader, it is structured. Is there a *key* in the record, or do you need to compare the full line?

Comment: @SergeBallesta need to compare the full line.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicate entries from a list you can convert the list to a set and convert it again to list.

```
import csv
csv_contents = request.vars['file'].value.decode('utf-8')
file = csv_contents.splitlines()
# Duplicate entries are removing
file_data = list(set([row for row in csv.DictReader(file)]))
```

As Serge Ballesta said the list order is not saved by using this method.